# Combine two object in RxJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, rxjs

I am working with rxjs and angular 2 inside of a service.  I have some json that I was able to access with a **get** request.

```
   private _campInfoUrl = 'api/campInfo/campInfo.json';
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getAvailableCamps() {  
    return this._http.get(this._campInfoUrl)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
```

At this point I have all of the data.  However to get into this object

```
      {
       "search": {
       "startDate": "2016-06-07",
       "endDate": "2016-06-10"
      },
       "reservations": [
       {"campsiteId": 1, "startDate": "2016-06-01", "endDate": "2016-06-04"},
       {"campsiteId": 1, "startDate": "2016-06-11", "endDate": "2016-06-13"},
       {"campsiteId": 2, "startDate": "2016-06-08", "endDate": "2016-06-09"}
  ] 
}
```

this is what i am trying to do

```
.map((response: Response) => response.json()) // <IProduct[]>
  .map((tripDate) => ({
    reservations: tripDate.reservations,
    newRes: tripDate.search // <-- how to add this to every return object
  }))
```

What I am struggling to figure out is a way with rxjs on how to get  **"search"**  inside of reservations array of objects like so

```
"reservations": [
 {
    "campsiteId": 1, 
    "startDate": "2016-06-01", 
    "endDate": "2016-06-04", 
     "searchStartDate": "2016-06-07, 
     "searchEndDate": "2016-06-10
 },
 {
    "campsiteId": 1, 
    "startDate": "2016-06-11", 
    "endDate": "2016-06-13",
    "searchStartDate": "2016-06-07, 
    "searchEndDate": "2016-06-10
 },
 {
   "campsiteId": 2, 
   "startDate": "2016-06-08", 
   "endDate": "2016-06-09",
   "searchStartDate": "2016-06-07, 
   "searchEndDate": "2016-06-10
 }
```

In the example above I have the search object added to each index of the reservations array.

I was hoping it was a matter of concatenating or mapping to transform the array.  However, I am not able to get inside of each index on the  reservations array

Any insight into navigating this json object would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you cannot get "inside each index", but you don't have to and you can even do this without RxJS:

```
.map((response: Response) => response.json()) // <IProduct[]>
  .map((tripDate) => ({
    reservations: tripDate.reservations
      .map(reservation => Object.assign(
        {},
        reservation,
        {
          searchStartDate: tripDate.search.startDate,
          searchEndDate: tripDate.search.endDate
        }
      )
    )
  }))
```

Comment: Jesus I can't thank you enough.  I literally was working with Object.assign and map.  I did not think to nest it though.